# Why can I assign an interface to a variable without any values?

Tags: typescript

I was testing TypeScript and found that I can make an interface and assign it any values, here, `person3` but can get away with not adding the `name` for it even though it does not have a `?` in front of it. Why is this allowed?

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age?: number; // Age is not compulsory
}

let person1: Person = { name: 'John', age: 13 };
let person3: Person;

console.log(person1);
console.log('');
console.log(person3); // Why does this not return an error and come as undefined instead?
```

Comment: The given code does give an error in TypeScript playground for me: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3ESXIxAPw0gCu5AEbRmyAPRjkAQU7JgGUljDIEWcgAc+AG2xQAngQC+BAlojL1mHAEYa6KNlwBefKQrVkAcgBSWABYgngA0yBwe1gDMyIasZhZWIBF2CawEqiDYZgB0WliMABSWDjYAlKzpmRA5efmenmVpOJXVBUWOEWXikgDqfnrIACZYEApgfvKKylDmfFC4cLjQUFhQoSADKmoocAp86xAwoBAboHQQcANcBEA

Comment: What options are in your `tsconfig`? You may be using less-strict settings.

Comment: @Dai I haven't set up a tsconfig as its just one file in which I'm learning how to use typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above, I made a `tsconfig.json` file and vscode added the error for me. So to fix this you have to make a tsconfig.json file with `tsc --init`.